# SQLite with LINQ integration into Visual Studio 2010 Express C#

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite

I have a project that I was originally using `XML` as the data source. I'm now refactoring the code to use a SQLite (`System.Data.SQLite`) data source. I have found numerous examples that show how to generate SQL queries, but I would prefer to use LINQ, because I'm more familiar with that approach.

I was originally using LINQpad, with LINQ expressions, to test my LINQ to Objects queries. Within LINQpad I created a connection to my database as well as a basic model information. Then I queried the db like this:

```
var site = (from s in siteinfo
            where s.site_name == "some name"
            select new Site
            {
              ID = s.id,
              State = s.state,
              City = s.city,
              ...
            }
           );
```

The LINQpad queries recognize the tables and columns within my database and I am able to generate my desired Objects.

Moving to VS 2010 Express I added the `System.Data.SQLite` and `System.Data.SQLite.Linq` references. Then I added a connection to my db within the data sources pane, which includes a `connectionString` in the `app.config` file.

**Question**: Should this connection should be added to my project as a Dataset (my current approach) or a Entity Data Model? I have tried both, but neither answer the question below.

When I try to recreate the LINQpad query from above, using VS, intellisense doesn't give me an option to select specific tables. Instead I have the option for `sitedata.siteinfoDataTable` and similar options for the other tables. For example:

```
var site = (from s in sitedataset.siteinfoDataTable
            where s.site_name == "some name"
            select new Site
            {
              ID = s.id,
              State = s.state,
              City = s.city,
              ...
            }
           );
```

I get the following error on the `sitedataset.siteinfoDataTable` reference:

`Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'sitedataset.siteinfoDataTable'. 'Where' not found.  Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?`

My project does reference the `Core.dll` and I have a `using` directive for `System.Linq`.

I also tried to query the distinct states from the dataset. For example:

```
var states = (from s in sitedataset.siteinfoDataTable
              select s.state).Distinct();
```

The `select` statement produces the following error:

`Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type`

**Question**: Using VS, how do I write a LINQ query against a SQLite database? How is that database schema recognized within VS?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!